# Using CASE with EXISTS in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an SQL select statement where I need to change a condition (where clause) based on a CASE statement. Basically I am using a where clause

```
AND dep_dt <= trunc(SYSDATE)
```

and I need to change <= to = if SYSDATE is a Monday. For all other days the operator will be <=.
Below is the SQL that I have written, but its not working.
Any help in writing the right logic is appreciated.

```
select distinct bip_sply_id 
    from purch_pay pp
    where exists (
        SELECT 1 FROM esp_roc_dtl esp
        where esp.bip_pymt_id=pp.bip_pay_id
        and esp.err_lvl_cd <>'555'
        and exists (
            CASE 
                WHEN trim((SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'Day') FROM dual)) = 'Monday' THEN 
                    SELECT 1 FROM  esp_pymt_trans_smry smry 
                    WHERE smry.bip_file_id= esp.bip_file_id
                    AND smry.bip_smry_id=esp.bip_smry_id
                    AND esp.bip_file_id = 
                        (select bip_file_id 
                        from bip_file_trk 
                        where file_type_id = 'TILR' 
                        and trunc(file_creat_ts) = 
                            (
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN trim((SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'Day') FROM dual)) = 'Monday' THEN 
                                            trunc(SYSDATE-2) 
                                    ELSE 
                                            trunc(SYSDATE-1) 
                                END
                            )
                        ) 
                    AND dep_dt = trunc(SYSDATE)    --= for Monday

            ELSE 
                    SELECT 1 FROM  esp_pymt_trans_smry smry 
                    WHERE smry.bip_file_id= esp.bip_file_id
                    AND smry.bip_smry_id=esp.bip_smry_id
                    AND esp.bip_file_id = 
                        (select bip_file_id 
                        from bip_file_trk 
                        where file_type_id = 'TILR' 
                        and trunc(file_creat_ts) = 
                            (
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN trim((SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'Day') FROM dual)) = 'Monday' THEN 
                                            trunc(SYSDATE-2) 
                                    ELSE 
                                            trunc(SYSDATE-1) 
                                END
                              )
                      ) 
                    AND dep_dt <= trunc(SYSDATE)   --<= for all other days
            END
           )
     )
    and  exists (
                    select 1 from sply_config_param conf2
                    where conf2.sply_config_param_id_seq_no =40
                    AND UPPER(conf2.sply_config_param_val) ='ON EXPECTED DEPOSIT DATE'
                    and conf2.sply_remit_orgn_id=pp.bip_sply_id
                    )
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is the most simplified representation of your problem

Comment: OMG. Pity the poor optimiser...

Comment: Did you try `AND dep_dt = trunc(SYSDATE) AND TRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day')) = 'Monday'` resp. `AND dep_dt <= trunc(SYSDATE) AND TRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Day')) != 'Monday'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make both comparisons in the same case statement:

```
and dep_dt = case when to_char( SysDate, 'D' ) <> '2'
                    and dep_dt <= SysDate then dep_dt 
                  else SysDate end
```

So if it's not Monday and dep_dt <= sysdate, the comparison becomes `dep_dt = dep_dt` which is true. If it's not Monday and dep_dt > sysdate, the comparison becomes `dep_dt = sysdate` which is false. If it is Monday, the comparison will be `dep_dt = sysdate` which will evaluate accordingly.

Be aware that this is susceptible to your NLS settings.